# Android Upload Build to Crashlytics with gradle

Tags: android, gradle, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I have troubles using `./gradlew assembleRelease crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease --stacktrace` command in my project.

This project was added to Crashlytics long time ago. Uploading works good when drag&drop apk manually but running this command gives me

**THIS ERROR:**

```
org.gradle.execution.TaskSelectionException: Task 'crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease' not found in root project 'myapp-mobile-android-base'.
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskSelector.getSelection(TaskSelector.java:101)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskSelector.getSelection(TaskSelector.java:76)
        at org.gradle.execution.commandline.CommandLineTaskParser.parseTasks(CommandLineTaskParser.java:42)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.configure(TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.java:44)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$100(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.execution.ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.configure(ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.java:47)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$100(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.configure(DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.java:44)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.select(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:142)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
```

**DESCRIPTION:**

I have this tag in my Manifest:

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            tools:replace="android:value"
            android:value="81352c31e84be4cd38eb7b760a39d6ca111111" />
```

In gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "http://cloudant.github.io/cloudant-sync-eap/repository" }
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
    }
    jcenter()
    maven {
        credentials {
            username NEXUS_USERNAME
            password NEXUS_PASSWORD
        }
        url MAVEN_REPO_BASE_SDK_URL

    }
    maven {
        credentials {
            username NEXUS_USERNAME
            password NEXUS_PASSWORD
        }
        url MAVEN_REPO_CORE_SDK_URL
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"


    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 15
        versionName "2.0.4"
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
            jni.srcDirs = []
            jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
        }
        production {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/production/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/production/res']
        }

        staging {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/staging/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/staging/res']
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        production {
            multiDexEnabled true
            applicationId "com.myapp"
            versionCode 40
            versionName "2.5.17"
        }

        staging {
            multiDexEnabled true
            applicationId "com.myapp_beta"
            versionCode 162
            versionName "2.5.17"
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        releaseMyapp {
            storeFile file("myapp.keystore")
            storePassword "myapp2015"
            keyAlias "myapp"
            keyPassword "myapp"
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        incremental true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseMyapp
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        def version = variant.productFlavors.get(0).versionName;
        def versionCode = variant.productFlavors.get(0).versionCode;

        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def outputFile = output.outputFile
            if (outputFile != null && outputFile.name.endsWith('.apk')) {
                def fileName = "myapp-${variant.name}-${version}(${versionCode}).apk"
                output.outputFile = new File(outputFile.parent, fileName)
            }

        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.myapp:myapp-core:2.2.5@aar'
    compile 'com.myapp:myapp:3.2.0@aar'

    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.cloudant:cloudant-sync-datastore-core:0.14.0'
    compile 'com.cloudant:cloudant-sync-datastore-android:0.14.0'
    compile 'com.cloudant:cloudant-sync-datastore-javase:0.14.0'
    compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
    compile 'net.orange-box.storebox:storebox-lib:1.3.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.3'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.3'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.jaredrummler:android-device-names:1.0.8'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-annotations:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.fernandocejas.frodo:frodo-api:0.8.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'
}
```

**EDIT:**

I fixed it by using  ./gradlew assembleRelease crashlyticsUploadDistributionProductionRelease --stacktrace command but my new apk doesn't appear at crashlytics either.

Comment: You have to signed the build before you can distribute it. For us: 
"WARN - Crashlytics halted compilation because it can't distribute the unsigned APK". You may have the same problem?